# Convert SuperBox JQuery to AngularJs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I found this amazing JQuery plugin by Todd Motto at http://toddmotto.com/introducing-superbox-the-reimagined-lightbox-gallery/.
I would like to convert this plugin to AngularJS directive as well as use html elements and not append new ones.
the original code is posted.
I made directive but it uses append instead of html elements,  http://plnkr.co/edit/JopooR3xyGAlwzKldZvk?p=preview
Thanks for the help!

```
;(function($) {

  $.fn.SuperBox = function(options) {

    var superbox      = $('<div class="superbox-show"></div>');
    var superboximg   = $('<img src="" class="superbox-current-img">');
    var superboxclose = $('<div class="superbox-close"></div>');

    superbox.append(superboximg).append(superboxclose);

    return this.each(function() {

      $('.superbox-list').click(function() {

        var currentimg = $(this).find('.superbox-img');
        var imgData = currentimg.data('img');
        superboximg.attr('src', imgData);

        if($('.superbox-current-img').css('opacity') == 0) {
          $('.superbox-current-img').animate({opacity: 1});
        }

        if ($(this).next().hasClass('superbox-show')) {
          superbox.toggle();
        } else {
          superbox.insertAfter(this).css('display', 'block');
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop:superbox.position().top - currentimg.width()
        }, 'medium');

      });

      $('.superbox').on('click', '.superbox-close', function() {
        $('.superbox-current-img').animate({opacity: 0}, 200, function() {
          $('.superbox-show').slideUp();
        });
      });

    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for an AngularJS version of Superbox. I couldn't find one either, that's why I started [angular-superbox](https://github.com/abuechler/angular-superbox). It might give you some ideas, or you might want to contribute.

Regards,
Andi